# Not able to change data stored in mongoDb database in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I wanna change button value after it submits a data into database,I've assigned a variable to button text and tried to set it's value from backend
but it is not working**

Here's my code

**BACKEND**

```
//after click action
 router.post('/accept/:id',isLoggedIn,function(req,res){

 User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, {$set:
        {'friendRequest.Status':'Accepted'}},function(err,founduser){
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {

               res.render('friendrequest',{user:founduser});
          }
        })
    })
```

**DATABASE MODEL**

*Here I put default value of button to "Accept" which should change to Accepted*

```
    var  mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password :String,



      friendRequest:[{      //Target database model
        id:{
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "User"
      },
        username: String,
     Status:{type:String,default:"Accept" }  //default value of button  
    }]



    UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

    module.exports = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

**FRONT END**

```
 <h3 id='username'><%= request.username %></h3>  

</div>
<div  class="four wide column">
<form  action = "/accept/<%=user.id%>" method = "post">
<button id="add" class="ui  medium  blue button"><%=request.Status%>
</button> 
</form>
```

***Or ,If any other method you can suggest which can work this out***

Comment: your friendRequest is an array, whereas you are updating it as an object. {'friendRequest[0].Status':'Accepted'} makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update object in an array use $ to match all indexes :

```
{$set: {'friendRequest.$.Status':'Accepted'}}
```

This will update all friendRequest of the user to the status Accepted.